# How to run Python file in vscode in python interpreter?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to make vscode as pyscripter IDE to load the variables in the python interpreter in terminal.

for example I have this file called `variables.py` with this content

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

a = -6
b = a * 2
c = a + b

if (a < 0):
    print(a)
    print(b)
else:
    print(c)
```

I can run it in vscode terminal by running this command **python3** `variables.py`

or i can open the **python interpreter** and load it as a **module** with

`import` or `exec` or `importlib` but after that I won't have access to, for example, the variable **a**

I can use the following command instead to have access

```
exec(open('variables.py').read())
```

This will give me access to content(variables) of the file.

```
>>> exec(open('variables.py').read())
-6
-12
>>> a
-6
>>> b
-12
```

but every time I make a change in the file I have to run the above command to load it again.

Is there a better way of making this automated.

instead of running the command in python interpreter every time i make a change to a file.

Comment: use 'Ctrl+Shift+P' and select Interpreter command from the Command Palette for more information go to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: even in a Jupiter Notebook you have to execute the modified code again, you can use the Python REPL